# Redirect query string to 404.php

Tags: php, string

Our sitemap got corrupted and Google listed all pages with the additional text `,0.8,daily`.
Example: `.php?pg=8,0.8,daily`

How do we get these links to redirect to, or return a, `404`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if( 8 == substr($_GET['pg'],0,1) )
    {
      header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
      die();
     }
```

if you want to 404 for any pg being set

```
if( isset($_GET['pg']) )
{
  header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
  die();
}
```

Comment: How do i do a green hook and how do i make the code independent of pg=8

Comment: Any page with a comma (,0.8,daily)

Comment: if( preg_match(  '/,0.8,daily/', $_GET['pg'] ))

for accepting the answer there is a hook you can check on the left of it.